# Maven with Vaadin Bean Validation?

Tags: java, maven, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm trying create an application using Maven and Vaadin Bean Validation to validate my beans, but doesn't now work to me.

I'm trying this.

```
@Entity
public class Person{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min=5, max=50, message="insert first name")
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Email
    private String email;

}

//my app
public class LoginView extends VerticalLayout{
     private TextField firstName, email;
     private BeanFieldGroup<Person> binder;
     private FormLayout form;

     public LoginView(){
         form = new FormLayout();
         binder = new BeanFieldGroup<Person>(Person.class);
         Field<?> field = null;

         field = binder.buildAndBind("Firstname", "firstName");
         firstName = (TextField)binder.getField("firstName");
         form.addComponent(firstName);

         field = binder.buildAndBind("Email", "email");
         email = (TextField)binder.getField("email");
         form.addComponent(email);

         this.addComponent(form);
     }
}
```

I added hibernate-validator as dependecy but still doesn't work. In vaadin bean validator documents says to use Hibernate Validator or agimatec-validation.

[image]

Which dependency I need to add for this work ?

The method isBeanValidationImplementationAvailable() returns true, Debug is bellow.

```
11:26:54,112 DEBUG [org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver] - Found javax.persistence.Persistence on classpath containing 'getPersistenceUtil'. Assuming JPA 2 environment. Trying to instantiate JPA aware TraversableResolver
11:26:54,113 DEBUG [org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver] - Instantiated JPA aware TraversableResolver of type org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.
11:26:54,113 DEBUG [org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.ValidationXmlParser] - Trying to load META-INF/validation.xml for XML based Validator configuration.
11:26:54,113 DEBUG [org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.ValidationXmlParser] - No META-INF/validation.xml found. Using annotation based configuration only.
Is bean validation implementation available: true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should validate when you call `binder.commit()`. Check out if you have `javax.validation.Validation` class on the classpath.

If it's not the case, please debug the `isBeanValidationImplementationAvailable()` static method on `BeanFieldGroup` and post any further details you found out.

Comment: I'm trying use the method isBeanValidationImplementationAvailable() with binder, but doesn't return autocomplete of eclipse. I'm using Vaadin7

Comment: Becouse it's protected. You should check out the source and place a breakpoint in the method. If you can't see the source code, go to Settings -> Maven and check the Download Artifact Sources + Download Artifact JavaDoc checkboxes.

Comment: ...I moved the method for a class, the method returns True

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the BeanValidationForm and BeanValidationValidator that come along with the Vaadin Bean Validation addon. 
You'll find some demo code at [svn](http://dev.vaadin.com/svn/addons/BeanValidation/trunk/demo/src/main/java/com/vaadin/addon/beanvalidation/demo/) for this addon.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, decided with included in dependencies `<artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>`